# What alternative word/phrase can I use in place of tryst?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Consider the hypothetical phrase,

> Google's *tryst* with hardware came in the form of Google Nexus phone product line, previously it was an exclusive software company.

"tryst" feels too textbook-y to me, can somebody recommend an alternative casual word?

Comment: You mean in 'the form **of the** Google Nexus phone product line'

Comment: Depending on the meaning you want,*[initial] **venture, foray, dabbling,*** for example, might all credible. But since ***tryst*** is effectively meaningless here, we don't have much idea what sense you intend. But the final clause is also incorrectly expressed, and I'm pretty sure the intended meaning *there* should be phrased as *previously it was **exclusively a** software company* (feasibly *...an exclusively software company*, but I think that would require *...exclusively **software-based** company*).

Comment: “Experiment” would work well in this hypothetical sentence. “Tryst” is not appropriate in any way. If I were writing whatever document this is, I would abandon this construction altogether and start over.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because synonyms for the word tryst can be found in a thesaurus *and* in any good dictionary

Comment: @Mari-LouA is correct. Besides, "Tryst" is likely a pretty good word to use. It's not "textbook-y," rather, it implies an inappropriate or undesirable relationship between Google and the hardware industry. It would be the perfect word to use if you believe Google Nexus was a mistake.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A A list of synonyms for "tryst" will not help here, because it seems to be used in an unusual metaphoric sense, and synonyms such as "meeting",  "rendezvous", or "assignation" will probably not be improvements, indeed they will be worse choices. A different metaphor is probably needed, which a thesaurus will not supply.

Answer (score 6):

*Tryst* is not 'too textbooky', it is definitely the wrong word. It means an arrangement to meet, usually between lovers.

You could say something like *Google's first venture into hardware.*

Comment: I took it as a form of dry humor, suggesting a higher level of passion for hardware than is usually encountered.  The word *venture* has no such association.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for *flirtation*.

Answer (score 0):

The main meaning of "tryst" is a private or secret meeting, usually for romantic or sexual purposes.  Less often it means a relationship, often a hidden one, derived from such a meeting.

I take its use here to be a metaphor, indicating an inappropriate or unwise extension of google's interest. In that msense it is not wrong, but it is a little obscure, and the reader may have to think a moment to understand the intention (unless additional context makes it clear). "flirtation", as suggested by cruthers is not bad, but suggests a brief and now ended episode, which "tryst" did not. Perhaps "passion for" or "obsession with" might do better. It depends just what the writer does want to convey about Google's actions.

Answer (score 0):

**Foray** is usually what I would use in this situation,

> an initial and often tentative attempt to do something in a new or different field or area of activity

I agree with others that *tryst* is typically used when describing some sort of clandestine sexual relationship, which makes it an odd choice to use when describing business.

*Foray* implies an endeavour that's something new to them and not particularly their strength, which makes sense in this sentence.